# Combining Log4Delphi and jcl debug

Tags: delphi, logging, delphi-xe3

At the moment I'm testing various logging framework for use in Delphi XE 3. Since using Log4Delphi made least problems concerning implementation into existing programs, I'm currently trying to get additional Informations for my logmessages. Now what I want to have are additional informations like method name and the line of code. I've already found the Jedi Code Librarys' debug functions might provide such data. Sadly I wasn't  able to figure out hot to get this to work the way I want it.

As it is I'm currently using this function:

```
function CurrentFunctionName: string;
begin
  Result := jcldebug.getlocationInfoStr(Caller(1));
end;
```

But while the code examples I've found provide data like this:

```
[004223A7] jcldebugtest.SomeProcedure (Line 10, "jcldebugtest.dpr")
```

All data I get when I'm trying to use it in my programs looks like this:

```
(00E8EF63) [0128FF63]
```

I don't fully understand the reason for this behavior, so it would be very nice if someone could explain to me how to do this properly and where my mistake/misunderstanding is located.

Comment: The help page for GetLocationInfoStr: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:GetLocationInfoStr states: `If location info was found, the function returns the formatted info string, otherwise it returns a string formatted as [Address].` That means it has not found any location info.

Comment: It looks you you either don't have debug info enabled in your project, or its stored in a location where `jcldebug` cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go into `Project->Options->Linker`, and turn on the `Detailed` map file, and then build (not compile!) your project. The map file information is necessary to convert from raw addresses to specific locations in the code.

You can test this using the example located in the `JCL\Examples\Windows\Debug\SourceLoc` folder. If you build and run the SourceLocExample.dpr, clicking the "Caller()", "Address lookup", or "Stack dump" buttons will return simply the memory addresses. Then follow the instructions above to enable the detailed map file, do a `Project->Build` from the IDE's menu, and run the example again, clicking the same buttons and comparing the output.

You can then (optionally) use the `Project->JCL Debug expert` to embed the debug info into your executable instead of providing it as a separate file that needs to be distributed.